# Render a component within another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a state is changed, React triggers `componentDidUpdate()` method, and by then I do:

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
  React.render(new SubmitButton, $('.uploader-submit').get(0));
}
```

As you saw, I'm rendering a `SubmitButton` when a specific state is changed, but my question is: is this the best behavior to get this feature done?

My scenario is: I'm uploading a photo. When the `input[type=file]` is changed, I create a new state property and then the `componentDidUpdate()` is triggered, invoking the SubmitButton.

This is my `render()` method:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <div className="uploader">
      <header className="uploader-header">
        <div className="uploader-actions pull-left">
          <div className="uploader-submit"></div>
          <CancelButton router={this.props.router} />
        </div>

        <UploadButton callback={this.imageSelectedCallback} />
      </header>

      <Preview imageUri={this.state.imageUri} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Couldn't I do something like the `<Preview />` component? I mean, it is there, but something just appears when `this.state.imageUri` is different of `null`. This is the implementation of `Preview`:

```
var Preview = {
  render: function () {
    return (
      <img src={this.props.imageUri} />
    )
  }
};

module.exports = React.createClass(Preview);
```

*Yes, I know — "Preview" is invisible by default because it is an image, but I want to know if there's another approach to reach what I want: to show something based on a state, using the `render` method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't render falsy values, be it a component or an attribute (like in the `Preview` case), e.g.

```
<div>{null}</div>
<img src={null} />
```

renders to

```
<div></div>
<img/>
```

So typically you just create a variable and conditionally assign it a component or null as was also suggested in another answer:

```
var button = null;
if(myConditionForShowingButton) {
    button = <SubmitButton />;
}
```

-- or simply --

```
var button = myConditionForShowingButton ?
    <SubmitButton /> :
    null;
```

In cases where the component gets bigger it's typically more readable and cleaner to have a subroutine for rendering that part

```
var complexComponent = condition ?
    this.renderComplexComponent() :
    null
```

Comment: Awesome! I thought this wasn't a good thing to do since we have methods such as `componentDidUpdate()` etc. But it is a smooth and simple solution that worked like a charm! Thank you to you and @reecer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [If-Else in JSX.](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

```
render: function () {
  var submitButton;
  if (this.state.imageSelected)
    submitButton = <SubmitButton />;

  return (
    <div className="uploader">
      <header className="uploader-header">
        <div className="uploader-actions pull-left">
          <div className="uploader-submit">{ submitButton }</div>
          <CancelButton router={this.props.router} />
        </div>

        <UploadButton callback={this.imageSelectedCallback} />
      </header>

      <Preview imageUri={this.state.imageUri} />
    </div>
  )
}
```